# Get all the zip codes within a n miles radius from another zip code

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, geolocation, geocoding

So, I'm doing radial search, and I need to get all the zip code in a X miles radius based on an actual zipcode.

For example, lets say that my location is in the zipcode 94111, i'll need to find all the zipcode that are in a 50 miles radius of my actual location.

I currently have a list of places in my database and we only stored the zipcode of those places. So I'll need to find all the places in a X miles radius based on my zipcode and their zipcodes.

I've no idea how to do it and what to use. I was thinking of the [geonames gem](http://www.tbcn.ca/ruby_geonames) bit it doesn't seems like it's possible.

Edit: we have a mysql DB

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will need [a database of zip codes](http://www.census.gov/tiger/tms/gazetteer/zips.txt) with geo coordinates. Mysql can do geo spatial search based on that.